# Make dynamic hyperlinks in Node-RED

Tags: javascript, http, node-red

I have a Template/HTML node in an Node-RED project, with hyperlinks like `<a href="/result/12345">...</a>`.

My question is: how to make a http request node that "dynamically" reads an URL such that, interprets "12345", and makes something? Must I connect a http req node to Template/HTML node?

I'm novice with Node-RED, so some things are new to me on it, though I have some experience with HTML, web-pages constructions, and so on.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you mean here, do you want to change the value after `/result` or read the value on an incoming request?

Comment: read the value on an incoming request. In HTML page, there is a link tagged by `<a href="/result/12345">...</a>`. What I wanna do is use a node that receives this "/result/12345", but this "12345" is dynamic, could be any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use express URL parameters in the Node-RED http-in node:

[image]

You can then access the variable as follows:

```
msg.req.param.id;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, @hardillb!